# How to give lots of header files to MATLAB loadlibrary?

Tags: c++, matlab, static-libraries

I have a program in C++ and compiled the program into a static library `.a` file. Now I want to use this library in MATLAB. Seemingly all remaining steps to use it in MATLAB is to give to MATLAB this `.a` library and the header files using `loadlibrary(libname,hfile)` command.

The problem is that my program consists of about 200 `.h` files located in different folders under the main source folder. How can I give all of these header files to MATLAB `loadlibrary`? I just started to integrating all of the headers into one header file; but is there a better, easier way to this?

Answer (score 0):

This will require some work on your part.

First option is to add additional header files in the [`loadlibrary` command](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loadlibrary.html)

```
loadlibrary('mylib','mylib.h','addheader','header2')
```

You'll need to have a list of all your additional header files.

Alternatively, you can explore the prototype file option instead of ehader file.
See [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/create-alias-function-name-using-prototype-file.html) for more information.